# JQM Flip Switches refresh after changing text not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/T4Y8j/1/

I am using a span with data-i18 to put all my translations in place...but I'm having an issue with the flip switch refreshing the new values. I'm having an identical problem with the select list as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for modifying the label of your switch would be to do the following:

**1 -** Isolate your switch in a DIV, and provide a specific ID (eg: `switch_container`) for this DIV, eg:

```
<div id="switch_container">

    <select name="slider" id="flipMe" data-role="slider">              
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on"></option>
    </select>

</div>
```

**2 -** Supposing that the label that you want to modify is in second position, you can use the following to change the label:

```
$('#switch_container .ui-slider .ui-slider-inneroffset .ui-slider-handle 
    .ui-slider-label:nth-child(1)').html("ok");
```

---

Here's a full working example that you can try in your JSFiddle:

**JS Code:**

```
$('#switch_container .ui-slider .ui-slider-inneroffset .ui-slider-handle .ui-slider-label:nth-child(1)').html("ok");

$('#flipMe').val('on').slider('refresh');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="switch_container">

    <select name="slider" id="flipMe" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on"></option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Hope this helps.